# How do I check if one logistic regression is better than another?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance

## Background

How often will it rain in the desert?

One set of predictions assigns grades to different spots in deserts around the world. A past study correlates the grades to chance of rain per day.

The grades ranges from extremely low (.01% per year) to much higher (20% per year), with most of the grades in the extremely low range.

## Question

My hypothesis is I can predict rain better - find spots that have a better chance of rain than expected. However, it rains very rarely - and I'm making my predictions across a wide variety of grades. Also, I don't want to overweight results in the areas that have a high chance of rain.

**How do I test for better logistic predictions?**

## Current thinking

My current plan is to:

1. Set up a logistic regression with [DidItRain?] vs [ExpectedProbability], [ExpectedProbability * DoIThinkThisOneIsRainier]
2. If [ExpectedProbability * DoIThinkThisOneIsRainier] is statistically significant, assume that I can predict better than the original prediction

**Are there hidden flaws in this plan?**

Comment: Why don’t you add DoIThinkThisOneIsRainier as regressor in the original logistic regression? Then check if AIC/BIC improves.

Comment: Good point, but I don't have access to the original regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to add an interaction to the model, then you should add both main effects to the model. Thus, if your model has the interaction of "expected probability" and "did I think this one is rainier" then it should have "did I think it rainier".

However, I am not sure you need an interaction at all.

Depending on exactly what your "did I think it rainier" variable is, you could either simply add your variable to the model or run two models, one with the expected probability via the old model and one with expected probability via your model.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Are there any dangerous effects from the varying probabilities (and sparseness in some regions)? I.e., will doing slightly better on the few rainy grades unfairly look statistically significant?

Comment: My reason (good?) for not including [DoIThinkThisOneIsRainier] is because of the wide range of expected probabilities. I'm worried this coefficient will skew towards "what happens in rainy areas?".

Comment: Including an interaction without the main effects is almost never right. And the wide range will also affect the interaction.